# replacing all matching values in datatable based on another in c#

Tags: c#

i have a dataTable like this : 
 [image]

and a second one like this : 
[image]

how can i replace `MIN_QUANTITY,MAX_QUANTITY,DISCOUNT_VALUE` from table two by the values in table 1 based on there `GEN_CODE`

**PS**:the `GEN_CODE` in the second table is not unique and can be duplicated and the duplicate rows should also be added in the first table 
i tried to use :

```
Table1.Merge(Table2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

but the duplicates rows are not added how should i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you stored every occurrences of table 1 and 2 into a "record" class that has every column of your datatable as a property.
It can be easily done using LINQ.

Let's say that records from table 1 are stored in `List<record> List1` and the other records from table 2 in `List<records> List2`.

```
foreach (record reference_record in List1)
{
      foreach(record record_to_update in List2.Where(x=>x.GEN_CODE == reference_record.GEN_CODE).Select(x=>x).ToList())
      {
          record_to_update.MIN_QUANTITY = reference_record.MIN_QUANTITY;
          record_to_update.MAX_QUANTITY = reference_record.MAX_QUANTITY;
          record_to_update.DISCOUNT_VALUE = reference_record.MAX_QUANTITY;
       }
}
```

You'll need to bind your data table on the following class:

```
public class record
{
    public string GEN_CODE { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string MIN_QUANTITY { get; set; }
    public string MAX_QUANTITY { get; set; }
    public string DISCOUNT_VALUE { get; set; }
    //... add other properties here
}
```

Comment: yeah thats exactly what my merge do bu what about the duplicates columns ? i want them to be added as well

Comment: The List2 will have its duplicated updated as well, since the 2nd foreach loop browse EVERY records of List2 that has the same "GEN_CODE" as the one selected in List1